# Search bar only working for first character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i have an api that i get data from and a search bar that in my react app.

my search bar look like this:

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp ={this.keyup} className="search"  />
```

and the keyup function is this:

```
keyup(event){
    let input1 = (event.target.value);
    console.log(input1);
    axios    
        .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/houses`)
        .then(res => {
            res.data.map(house=>{
                if(house.title.includes(input1)){
                    console.log(house);
                }
            })
        })
}
```

when i type into the search bar it works, but only to the first character, after that it doesn't work.
For example i have 6 titles and 3 with the letter 's', if i type in 's' in the search bar, it will show me the 3 titles, but if i type 'su' which only i 1 title has, it doesn't do anything, same for any other letter.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What does your data looks like ?

Comment: first of all, you don't need to fetch data inside keyup each time if you are filtering on frontend, 2ndly, you should lowercase both strings before to compare, maybe you have upper and lowercase characters in title.

Comment: If service call required try using debounce to optimise service call, lower or capitalize both( user input and response) before comparing, Change onKeyUp to onChange works better.

Comment: @AtifSaddique, yes that was it, thank you so much, i will take care of the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to fetch data inside keyup each time if you are filtering on frontend,

2ndly, you should lowercase both strings before to compare, maybe you have upper and lowercase characters in title.